# ROS in docker-compose leads to "bash: line 0: cd: MYPROJECT: No such file or directory"

Tags: mount, docker, wsl2, docker-compose

I am a clear beginner at docker and I try to create a docker-compose where two containers can see each other. It could be that this question is a duplicate of many others about the "No such file or directory" error, but other questions have not helped me up to now solving this.

It is for a ROS project, the frame is taken from "[Small ROS example](https://gist.github.com/ruffsl/4a24c26a1aa2cc733c64)", and there, mainly the [docker-compose-explicit.yml](https://gist.github.com/ruffsl/4a24c26a1aa2cc733c64#file-docker-compose-explicit-yml) example, and that tutorial works.

Now, using my project image and changing a few other things:

- The bridge network works, this is tested with simple "hello world" echos and `ping master` aso.
- I am not sure about the volumes of the resolvable.

I do not find a way to get to the working directory of the image the way that the container seems to do it automatically. **It seems as if I do not mount MYPROJECT, which was installed in /root when I created the image.**

This run of a container works without a mount parameter, it seems to start with the root as the working directory of the image automatically and then can access the MYPROJECT directory without errors:

```
docker run -it --rm --name test MYPROJECT /bin/bash -c "cd MYPROJECT"
```

This docker-compose file does not work. I have added `ls` to see "what the container sees at that moment":

```
version: '2'

services:

  master:
    build: .
    networks:
      - MYPROJECT_bridge
    command: bash -c "echo 'hello world' && cd MYPROJECT && ls"  

  talker:
    build: .
    networks:
      - MYPROJECT_bridge
    environment:
      - "ROS_HOSTNAME=talker.MYPROJECT_bridge"
      - "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://master.MYPROJECT_bridge:11311/"
    command: bash -c "echo 'hello world' && ls && echo '___' && cd MYPROJECT && ls"

  listener:
    build: .
    networks:
      - MYPROJECT_bridge
    environment:
      - "ROS_HOSTNAME=listener.MYPROJECT_bridge"
      - "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://master.MYPROJECT_bridge:11311/"
    command: bash -c "echo 'hello world' && ls && echo '___' && cd MYPROJECT && ls"

# "resolvable" is providing a DNS entry for the Docker bridge interface address, by default for docker0, just to avoid having to set ROS_IP for every container, see the tutorial

  resolvable:
    image: MYIMAGE
    volumes:
      - /:/MYPROJECT:rw
    command: bash -c "echo 'hello world';tail -f /dev/null;"

volumes:   
  MYPROJECT:

networks:   
  MYPROJECT_bridge:
```

Example error output from the listener:

```
Attaching to MYPROJECTPATH_listener_1, MYPROJECTPATH_resolvable_1
resolvable_1  | 2021/02/06 10:43:42 systemd: disabled, cannot read /tmp/systemd: stat /tmp/systemd: no such file or directory
resolvable_1  | 2021/02/06 10:43:42 Starting resolvable 0.2 ...
resolvable_1  | 2021/02/06 10:43:42 got local address: 172.26.0.2
resolvable_1  | 2021/02/06 10:43:42 error adding container 98682f299611: unknown network mode%!(EXTRA string=MYPROJECTPATH_MYPROJECT_bridge)
resolvable_1  | 2021/02/06 10:43:42 error adding container 55f741dabd1c: unknown network mode%!(EXTRA string=MYPROJECTPATH_default)
listener_1    | hello world
listener_1    | bin
listener_1    | boot
listener_1    | dev
listener_1    | etc
listener_1    | home
listener_1    | lib
listener_1    | lib64
listener_1    | media
listener_1    | mnt
listener_1    | opt
listener_1    | proc
listener_1    | root
listener_1    | ros_entrypoint.sh
listener_1    | run
listener_1    | sbin
listener_1    | srv
listener_1    | sys
listener_1    | tmp
listener_1    | usr
listener_1    | var
listener_1    | ___
listener_1    | bash: line 0: cd: MYPROJECT: No such file or directory
```

How to fix this last line, `No such file or directory`? It cannot cd in the MYPROJECT directory.

The question might also cover, though I am not sure: Why and how do I have to mount the volume in a docker-compose file when using the same bash command that is already working on a container without a mount parameter? And there are warnings at the start `cannot read /tmp/systemd` and `unknown network mode%`, but that error also appears in the tutorial and does not stop it from working.

UPDATE: If I load the image in each of the services (so that you have `image: MYIMAGE` also in master, talker and listener), the commands work in each service, though they do not find the master:

`RLException: ERROR: unable to contact ROS master at [http://master.MYPROJECT_bridge:11311] talker_1      | The traceback for the exception was written to the log file`.

How can I load the image only once in the resolvable so that the other services use that image? Or more broadly, if the resolvable is perhaps not needed: How can I get ROS working on Docker using docker-compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The better step is to take another ROS compose tutorial, see 2.).

1. Trying to run the given docker-compose:

I cannot say for sure anymore what is the main change. This is at least working in the end.

```
version: '2'

services:

  master:
    build: .
    command: roscore 

  talker:
    build: .
    workdir: /MYPROJECT
    environment:
      - "ROS_HOSTNAME=talker"
      - "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://master:11311/"
    command: bash -c "source devel/setup.bash && MYCOMMAND --wait"

  listener:
    build: .
    workdir: /MYPROJECT
    environment:
      - "ROS_HOSTNAME=listener"
      - "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://master:11311/"
    command: bash -c "source devel/setup.bash && MYCOMMAND --wait"

  resolvable:
    image: MYIMAGE
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
      - /etc/resolv.conf:/tmp/resolv.conf
```

And if I wanted to `cd MYPROJECT &&` instead of using the `workdir:`, I might have to mount the volume in *each* container, not just in the "resolvable" container. See [Mount a volume in docker-compose. How is it done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228386/mount-a-volume-in-docker-compose-how-is-it-done) and [How to mount a host directory with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157161/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-with-docker-compose?noredirect=1&lq=1) or the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Although taking the guide of 2.) is likely the best way, this is a way to get the docker-compose of the question working, using a slim script without separate networks and volumes, since that is covered by the "resolvable" container. You need to add  `--wait` (without `;` before it) at the end of the command line of the bash commands of talker and listener; that  `--wait` aims at the same as `;tail -f /dev/null`, which also keeps the container alive, but there is no `;`. Using  `--wait` has worked in tests and could even be the main trick.

2. The more official wiki.ros.org guide seems to be better:

Taking advice from the fairly official wiki.ros.org guide, [Getting started with ROS and Docker Compose](https://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Compose), here is just a copy and paste at first:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  ros:
    driver: bridge

services:
  ros-master:
    image: ros:kinetic-ros-core --> replace with MYIMAGE
    command: stdbuf -o L roscore
    networks:
      - ros
    restart: always

  talker:
    image: ros:kinetic-ros-core --> replace with MYIMAGE
    depends_on:
      - ros-master
    environment:
      - "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ros-master:11311"
      - "ROS_HOSTNAME=talker"
    command: stdbuf -o L rostopic pub /chatter std_msgs/String "hello" -r 1
    networks:
      - ros
    restart: always

  listener:
    image: ros:kinetic-ros-core --> replace with MYIMAGE
    depends_on:
      - ros-master
    environment:
      - "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ros-master:11311"
      - "ROS_HOSTNAME=listener"
    command: stdbuf -o L rostopic echo /chatter
    networks:
      - ros
    restart: always
```

Instead of `stdbuf -o L ...` you can also use `bash -c "..."`.

What is the difference with the docker-compose of the question?

- The network is built with an additional step:

  ```
    networks:
      ros:
        driver: bridge
  ```

  This network is called in the containers with:

  ```
        networks:
          - ros
  ```

  While the docker-compose of the question uses

  ```
    networks:
      - MYPROJECT_bridge
  ```

  and calls the network with the same:

  ```
    networks:
      - MYPROJECT_bridge
  ```
- We also see that the "resolvable" container is not needed at all.
- `restart: always` is introduced so that the containers do not exit directly after one command, likely doing the same as  `--wait` at the end of the bash command in 1.). The docker-compose of the question uses `tail -f /dev/null` just for the resolvable, in the probably wrong hope that this would hold for the usage of the image in all containers.